# IF (AND) Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm new doing IF & And statements and am wondering why this line doesn't work?

=IF(OR(AND(D15<=2, P15>= TIMEVALUE ("0:03:01")), AND(D15>=3, P15>= TIMEVALUE ("0:20:01")), "Over 3 mins", "Over 20 mins")

Would appreciate if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Can you let us know what you're trying to do? Are you getting an error? If so, what is it. If not, what is happening instead of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Something I like to do with complicated function calls like this, is to format the text with indenting, and using a text software, like Notepad++, which can highlight parenthesis for you. When I moved it into Notepad++, and formatted it, it looks like you're missing a parenthesis at the end of the 2nd line.

```
=IF(OR(AND(D15<=2, P15>= TIMEVALUE ("0:03:01")), 
        AND(D15>=3, P15>= TIMEVALUE ("0:20:01"))), 
    "Over 3 mins", 
    "Over 20 mins")
```

Comment: Thank You for the help! :D

Comment: No problem. I'd appreciate an upvote if this resolved your issue :)